# Meteor: Adding fields to Third Party User creation

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using the [user-accounts](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core) package to manage the Account System in my app.

I have also integrated Google, Github, Twitter and other 3rd party Services.

The package works fine, but now that I need a specific page for every user, and for SEO terms, I need the url to be like this:

`https://domain.com/user/username`

I also have the accounts-password package. And I have added a username field, and it works fine.

But if thirdparty services are used, the popup closes and the page is redirected with the user successfully created. I read about calling `Accounts.onUserCreate`,
and this is my code:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  var email = options.profile.email;
 var ist = email.indexOf("@");
 var uname = email.slice(0,ist);
 user.username = uname;

if(options.profile){
user.profile = options.profile;
}
  return user;
});
```

But it gives an error : `Cannot read indexOf of undefined.`

How can this be achieved?

There either can be a page, to enter the username, for every new user, or this way, the email should be sliced for username creation. (Second method is preferred.)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you your variable email has not been set.

When using third-party login services with Meteor, the user information is not stored within the `profile` of the user document. Rather, you should look for the email within the `services` data of that user document. For example, for Facebook, you should find this within `services.facebook.email`.

You may also want to consider using the `user` argument to find this information as the documentation states: "*The user argument is created on the server and contains a proposed user object with all the automatically generated fields*".

Comment: This does put light on the issue, but it doesn't solve it.

Comment: Sorry this wasn't explicit enough. Your first statement won't work for third-party services as `options.profile.email` does not exist - hence evaluates to `undefined`. Therefore, you have effectively said `var email = undefined`.

You might want to change your code to set `email` to whichever third-party service is being used - something like `var email = user.profile.email || user.services.facebook.email || //...(your other login services)`